# How can i take a picture with custom camera and display it on another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, photo

Please help me how to take a picture from a custom camera and display it on another activity, please give me more detailed answer, what code should i put, and where, please tell me if what kind of variables, int, strings, booleans should i create,
here is my code :

Main Activity :

Comment: Haven't read through but can you store image data to local file storage and pass the path with Bundle to an activity ?  and in second Activity, you can read from the local file storage.

Comment: i tried it with bundle but i cannot get it to save to local file storage, idk why,  it doesnt display, it shuts down my app while testing

Comment: You tried to store before you are sending ?   You basically need to pass only string path to the local file via bundle.   Also you may need to consider compressing before storing.

Comment: Can you please send me an example of code because i dont understand very well what you are saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

    // Store bitmap to local storage
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        // Prepare file path to store bitmap
        // This will create Pictures/MY_APP_NAME_DIR/
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MY_APP_NAME_DIR");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Bitmap will be stored at /Pictures/MY_APP_NAME_DIR/YOUR_FILE_NAME.jpg
        String filePath = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "YOUR_FILE_NAME.jpg";
        out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You can use interface to pass YOUR_FILE_PATH from CameraPreview class to MainActivity class.
then in MainActivity.java

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, EditPicture.class);
i.putExtra("FILE_PATH", YOUR_FILE_PATH);
startActivity(i);
```

in EditPicture activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getIntent().hasExtra("FILE_PATH")) {
        String filePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("FILE_PATH");

        // Read bitmap from local file
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        yourImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Finally, add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` to your AndroidManifest.xml in order to allow your app writing to external storage.

This is the example of how to write bitmap to external storage. If you want to store to internal storage such as cache or other options, please refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Let me know if you need me to elaborate more.

Comment: it seems reachable to me , i only have 2 little problems, the "FILE PATH" and "YOUR_FILE_PATH" since i am a C++ C# developer that learned android for 4 months until now, i never had to do with photos, now this makes me a lot of problems, how do i have to set them (FILE_PATH) and YOUR_FILE_PATH ?

Comment: Updated an answer.  "FILE_PATH" is a string tag for bundle.  You can name it as you wish.   You just have to have a same string tag for putExtra and getStringExtra

Comment: thanks, but the YOUR_FILE_PATH ? SORRY TO BE ASKING SO MUCH , I KNOW IT'S ANNOYING BUT I MUST COMPLETE THIS APP this week

Comment: No worries.  I updated the code so that YOUR_FILE_PATH is gone :)   You can refer code again and see how you can get your path.

Comment: I putted the intent in a void, and call after taking photo in the onclick method, it works fine but the activity launches and there is no photo shown, what should i do ?

Comment: it doesn't display the picture in the EditPictureActivity, what should i do, i think the problem is in the MainActivity, i've put the intent in a void, and call after captureImage(); , the activity launches and there's no photo shown, please help !

Comment: It is getting beyond the original question.  Could you open a new question with specific detail and specific code around to reproduce a bug?  Also, before that, could you check your Android data to see picture is properly stored into SD ? You can use https://www.android.com/intl/en_us/filetransfer/ or similar tool to browse your files.

Comment: it is the same question, i tried your code, and i tried to show you the result, i know i did something wrong but if you could help me figure it out !

Comment: This question was "how" and your question now is more about how to fix a bug on intent or fail to read a file from SD, so you can post more concise and precise code to ask for a better answer and I should not put an answer in comments. Besides, please add your original code back to question but a shorter one which only includes functions relating to this question.

Comment: i will add it again after 30 min, i am trying some different methods, thanks again for your help, i hope i can find a solution